# Placing an invisible link over a background image

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a background image loaded into a column on wordpress. Over this image I want to insert a transparent box to make the image clickable (as background images cannot be linked)

```css
#container {
  background-image: url(https://www.quanser.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/QBOT2e-Banner2.png);
  width: 670px;
  height: 700px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0px 240px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h6><strong><br>
    Do you want to move your research to the next level, beyond simulation? Are you looking for a way to speed up and advance your work?</strong></h6>
  <p>For 30 years, Quanser platforms help researchers worldwide develop an effective research regimen that connects advanced theoretical and algorithm framework and real-world implementation.<br> Combining control plants with dynamics sufficient for physically
    relevant testing, and a real-time computational and modeling framework, our systems represent ideal testbeds for rapid testing of algorithms and research theories. Over 3,000 research publications are a solid testament!<br> Our continuing innovations
    ensure we can offer you the right tools, whether your interest lies in classic control, distributed control, autonomous<br> robotics, cyber-physical systems, and other emerging<br> control areas.<br>
    <strong><br>
    Win one of our research platforms – get an<br>
    autonomous ground robot for your lab</strong></p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p style="font-size: 9px; line-height: 11px; padding-top: 23px;"><strong>Contest Rules:</strong>&nbsp;To enter a draw for a complete QBot 2e system (includes the ground robot vehicle, one QUARC software Autonomous license, and a wireless router), fill the form on this page before September 31, 2019. The draw will
    be held on October 4, 2019, and the results will be announced by email.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not put a link around the container?

Comment: I only want the image and the text before it to be a link. If the whole text is clickable it will create hassle. We have a Call to Action on the image so we want them to click around there. I was hoping to make the link cover that.

Comment: Then work with HTML and CSS to support that use case. That would mean creating a container for the image only, with e.g. an absolute positioned element (for the text, and CTA) which will be positioned on top of the image container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an absolutely positioned link over the image.

In this example I've made it the same size and shape as the red circle in your image but you can resize and reposition it as you see fit. Additional info in comments.

```css
#container {
  background-image: url(https://www.quanser.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/QBOT2e-Banner2.png);
  /* removed height and width so it will wrap and fit neatly in smaller viewports */
  min-width: 370px;  /* set minimum width so its always at least as wide as the red circle part of the graphic */
  max-width: 670px;  /* set max width so its never wider than the graphic*/
  padding-bottom: 105px;  /* added padding so now things should fit & line-up regardless of the font-size or width. (Try resizing viewport) */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right bottom;  /* positioned bg at bottom right */
  position: relative;  /* set position relative so the absolutely positioned #hotspot stays aligned */
  overflow: hidden;  /* hidden any overflow in order to crop the hotspot */
}
#rules {
 font-size: 9px; 
 line-height: 11px; 
 width:calc(100% - 300px);
 }
#hotspot {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -59px;
  bottom: -144px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 360px;
  width: 360px;
}
#hotspot:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

/* added a little responsive styles for on narrow devices */
@media (max-width:450px) {
  #container {
    padding-bottom: 210px;
  }
  #rules {
   width:100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h6><strong><br>
    Do you want to move your research to the next level, beyond simulation? Are you looking for a way to speed up and advance your work?</strong></h6>
  <p>For 30 years, Quanser platforms help researchers worldwide develop an effective research regimen that connects advanced theoretical and algorithm framework and real-world implementation.<br> Combining control plants with dynamics sufficient for physically
    relevant testing, and a real-time computational and modeling framework, our systems represent ideal testbeds for rapid testing of algorithms and research theories. Over 3,000 research publications are a solid testament!<br> Our continuing innovations
    ensure we can offer you the right tools, whether your interest lies in classic control, distributed control, autonomous<br> robotics, cyber-physical systems, and other emerging<br> control areas.<br>
    <strong><br>
    Win one of our research platforms – get an<br>
    autonomous ground robot for your lab</strong></p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p id="rules"><strong>Contest Rules:</strong>&nbsp;To enter a draw for a complete QBot 2e system (includes the ground robot vehicle, one QUARC software Autonomous license, and a wireless router), fill the form on this page before September 31, 2019. The draw will
    be held on October 4, 2019, and the results will be announced by email.</p>
  <a id="hotspot" href="#somelink" title="Learn more about QBot 2e"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey bud thanks for your help. I am pretty close with this but can't seem to force the hover to be over the circle.

Comment: Also thank you for your help in advance I really appreciate it

Comment: @MichaelBrowne your example at quanser.com/research is somewhat different to the HTML you posted in your original question. To get the hover shape positioned over the circle graphic you need a wrapper that contains the graphic positioned at the bottom. The hotspot is then also positioned at the bottom right relative to that container.

Comment: @MichaelBrowne In your live version the background image needs to be positioned at the bottom right `#container {background-position: right bottom;}` and the hotspot needs to be at the bottom: `#hotspot {right: -59px; bottom: -144px;}`. If you want the 'Rules' to be below the graphic you should place them outside of the `#container`.

Comment: Resize your browser. You'll see why its not lining up at quanser.com/research. In your code you have the background image at a fixed position 270px from the top. When the viewport is narrow the text reflows and thus takes up more vertical space and will overflow your background image.

Comment: With some tinkering I got this to work thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

I just update your code with few changes. Try this i hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
#container {
  width: 670px;
  height: 700px;  
}

#footerWrap {
  background-image: url(https://www.quanser.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/QBOT2e-Banner2.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0 bottom;  
  position: relative;
  height: 215px;
  width: 100%;
}

#transparentLink {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  right: 13px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 254px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h6><strong><br>
    Do you want to move your research to the next level, beyond simulation? Are you looking for a way to speed up and advance your work?</strong></h6>
  <p>For 30 years, Quanser platforms help researchers worldwide develop an effective research regimen that connects advanced theoretical and algorithm framework and real-world implementation.<br> Combining control plants with dynamics sufficient for physically
    relevant testing, and a real-time computational and modeling framework, our systems represent ideal testbeds for rapid testing of algorithms and research theories. Over 3,000 research publications are a solid testament!<br> Our continuing innovations
    ensure we can offer you the right tools, whether your interest lies in classic control, distributed control, autonomous<br> robotics, cyber-physical systems, and other emerging<br> control areas.<br>
    <strong><br>
    Win one of our research platforms – get an<br>
    autonomous ground robot for your lab</strong></p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <div id="footerWrap">
    <p style="font-size: 9px; line-height: 11px; padding-top: 23px;"><strong>Contest Rules:</strong>&nbsp;To enter a draw for a complete QBot 2e system (includes the ground robot vehicle, one QUARC software Autonomous license, and a wireless router), fill the form on this page before September 31, 2019. The draw will
      be held on October 4, 2019, and the results will be announced by email.</p>
    <a href="#" id="transparentLink"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The position of the image matters as it needs to be after the text in the body. That is why we made it a background image in order to allow text to overlay onto the image. How can I ensure the position stays where it is?

Comment: Because we create `footerWrap` container which is dependent on text if text increase/decrease it'll slide down/up and it'll not disturb link position. Unless you change `container` width this is the only thing will disturb the link. Thanks